# Advice for Simple AWS CLI provisioning on Free Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, aws-cli, aws-cloudformation

PREFACE: I'm not asking "how do you do this?".

I'd be very grateful to hear your opinion on the appropriate AWS solution(s) based on the following criteria.

- It's basically "hello world".
- It's served up as HTML (so, webserver)
- I have an AWS account
- I have or can regenerate IAM keypairs
- I want to avoid the dashboard.  (I'd like it to be from one sort of CLI)
- I'm cool with python, ruby, bash, etc.
- This is in no way production.  This can have a strange IP, no database, and load balancing isn't a factor.

Again, to be clear, I'm not asking "how?".  I'm wondering about the most appropriate approach, based on the previously mentioned criteria.

I'm just a confused man.   There's a lot of solutions out there.  There's EC2, Cloudformation, OpsWorks, Static from S3, Elastic Beanstalk.......etc. There's almost a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nothing but serving up static HTML, you can just upload your HTML content to an S3 bucket configured as a static website. Here's a simple shell script that creates a "Hello world" site from the AWS CLI:

```
#!/bin/sh

BUCKET=my-s3-bucket
REGION=us-east-1
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket $BUCKET --region $REGION
aws s3 website s3://$BUCKET --index-document index.html
aws s3 sync . s3://$BUCKET --acl public-read
echo "Visit your website: http://$BUCKET.s3-website-$REGION.amazonaws.com"
```

This script uses the following CLI commands:

- [`aws s3api create-bucket`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-bucket.html)
- [`aws s3 website`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/website.html)
- [`aws s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Just customize `BUCKET` and `REGION` as desired and run the script (or just copy/paste each command directly) from the directory containing your "hello world" `index.html` file and any other content you want to publish to your site. To update the site with new content after it's already created, just run the `aws s3 sync` line by itself.

Answer (score 2):

To get things going quickly and to learn the building blocks of AWS hands-on, I would ignore CloudFormation, OpsWorks, and Elastic Beanstalk. Learning their intricacies will take time.

Either write static content directly to a bucket in S3 and then enable [S3 website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html), or launch an EC2 instance and [bootstrap](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) the instance from EC2 userdata. Which you should do depends on the eventual goal of the website. If it's always going to be static, then S3 hosting may be fine.

Here's a [30-minute python webapp](https://github.com/jsh2134/thirty-min-app) on AWS that someone built going with the latter approach, with a little more sophistication via fabric.

Comment: Another option is to use something like [chalice](https://github.com/awslabs/chalice), though if your website is static I would also recommend using S3. I would be hesitant about that 30 minute web app - it looks like it hasn't seen any updates in 5 years and a lot has changed since then.